# Microsoft Update Assistant : File not found (Valid file paths)

Tags: .net, .net-core

Having an issue trying to migrate a dotnet framework 4.8 webapi project to dotnet 6.
The upgrade tool works well on all classes in the project itself, but fails all of my external libraries with

```
Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Transformers.CopyFileTransformer
info: Could not find file 'C:\source\path\to\file.cs'.
info: Done
Microsoft.IntelliCode.Transformations.Upgrade.UserAgentProseUgradeTransformer
info: CouldNotFindFileUnderSourceProject
Retry 1
info: CouldNotFindFileUnderSourceProject
```

Anyone run into this issue? I have confirmed up and down the path it prints out is correct and the file is there.

Comment: I just found the same issue on a bunch of files Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Transformers.CopyFileTransformer
 info: Could not find file 'C:\code\sln\src\proj.Commons\Check.cs'.
 info: Done
 Microsoft.IntelliCode.Transformations.Upgrade.UserAgentProseUgradeTransformer
 info: CouldNotFindFileUnderSourceProject
 Retry 1

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens for me when the classes the migration is attempting to migrate are in a different assembly from the web project.
To prevent this issue, uncheck any classes in the migration dialog that are not in your assembly. As long as you have followed the guidance of moving your other assemblies to .net standard already, this will work correctly.